# Android confirm dialog dont wait for the user

Tags: android

I have that code here:

```
 int flagconfirm;

      public void resultado(View v)
     {
     warning();

     if(flagconfirm==0)
     return;

     finish();
     }

public void warning()
    {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                int flag=0;
                switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        flagconfirm=1;
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        return;
                }
            }

        };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Exit?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();

    }
```

But the problem is the compiler call the function and continue the work, it don't wait for the answer of the user. So i need to click  the button 2 times, and accept 2 times.
Can anyone help me?Thanks.

Comment: Why do you call finish() after showing the dialog? It will oficially close the Activity and this way the Dialog with it.

Comment: If the flagconfirm is 0 dont execut the finish()

Comment: refer this link...http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for user Input is done asynchronously, so, when you create and show your AlertDialog, rest of the method body continues execution. You have to either stop the execution(BAD when on GUI thread, which is the case now), or call some method from the listener. Modify your structure to something like this:

```
public void resultado(View v) {
    warning();
}

dialogClickListener = ...{
    int flag=0;
            switch (which){
                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    parsePositive();
                    break;

                case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    parseNegative(dialog); 
                    return;
            }  }

void parsePositive(){finish();}
void parseNegative(DialogInterface dialog){dialog.dismiss();}
```

Comment: Can you complet more the code? Im new in android and dont understand to many thinks

Comment: I just updated my answer. If you need help with such easy topics, you should learn at least basic Java and and only then move to Android.

Comment: Thanks to the help anyway.

Comment: the `void parsePositive(){finish();}
void parseNegative(DialogInterface dialog){dialog.dispose();}` is inside the function warning? or outside?

Comment: Ok its almost working, just the `void parseNegative(DialogInterface dialog){dialog.dispose();}` give me error in `dialog.dispose();` Error: cant resolve method dispose()

Comment: For more Information, refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Sorry about dispose, should be `dismiss`

Comment: But its any way to do in the way i want? becouse ill use the confirm dialog to another methods. Ill need to continue the method or not.

Comment: Anyone can help? i realy need this please

Comment: Probably is better do another question